# ons-alert-dialogの表示スタイルを変更したい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

[ons-alert-dialog](http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-alert-dialog.html)を使用して表示されるアラートダイアログのスタイルを変更したいです。

ブラウザからサンプルを開くと、アラートダイアログはiOSのようなデザインで表示されるのですが、Android上で同じスクリプトを実行するとアラートダイアログはAndroidのようなデザインで表示されてしまいます。

onsenUIのドキュメントによるとmodifierでandroidと指定することで、iOSのデザインをAndroidのデザインにする方法は書かれているのですが、その逆は書かれていません。

どうすればiOSのデザインをAndroidで利用できるでしょうか？
(ons-toolbarにおけるfixed-styleのようなことをしたい。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ons-alert-dialog>`をandroidで開くとandroid用のmodifierが自動で設定されて以下のCSSが効いてしまいます。

```
.alert-dialog--android {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.alert-dialog-title--android {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
.alert-dialog-content--android {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

これを上書きするCSSを自分で書いてやればOKです。

`modifier="ios"`とでもして、`onsen-css-components.css`の`.alert-dialog`の辺りを読みつつお好みで以下のようにCSSを設定してください。

```
.alert-dialog--ios{
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 16px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}
.alert-dialog-title--ios{
  border-bottom: none;
  height: initial;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.alert-dialog-content--ios{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 12px 8px 12px;
}
```

Comment: 無事変更できました！ありがとうございました。